# Apache2 route to a different folder based on location match

Tags: apache2

I would like to reroute my apache to a different system folder.

Currently I have this setting

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName blaah.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/blaah.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/blaah.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blaah
    Alias /webalizer /var/www/webalizer
    <Directory /var/www/webalizer>
        Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
        Deny from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName webalizer
        AuthUserFile /var/www/webalizer/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /gogs http://127.0.0.1:3000
    <LocationMatch "^/blaah/blaah/">
        Deny from all
    </LocationMatch>
    <LocationMatch "^/maintenance">
        Allow from IP
        Deny from all
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

So basically when going to servername blaah.com you get directed to a service.

Now I want to do a maintenance on that service, that means I have to reroute them.

But I want to test out that endpoint, so when you write blaah.com/maintenance (the last Location Match should cover that) you get directed to /var/www/maintenance. That folder holds a single index.html that tells you that an maintenance is underway. How can I accomplish that?

In nginx I would do multiple locations and then change document root and tryfiles.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Used

```
  Alias /maintenance /var/www/maintenance
  <Directory /var/www/maintenance">
      Allow from IP
  </Directory>
```